# my tic-tac-toe doesn't return the winner on column 2 and 3

Tags: c

I have a tic-tac-toe C program. My problem is that all winning conditions is fine, except whenever there is a 3 'X' or 'O' in column 2 or 3, the program doesn't return the winner, the program will keep running until there are no spaces left or the other player(or the computer) wins. But, if there are 3 'X' or 'O' on the first column, the game will stop and return the winner. I had tried to fix it but i couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here are my winning conditions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
char board[3][3];
const char PLAYER ='X';
const char PLAYER2 = 'O';
const char BOT ='O';

void resetBoard(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            board[i][j]=' ';
        }
    }
}

void printWinner(char winner){
    if (winner==PLAYER){
        printf("\nPlayer 1 wins!");
    }
    else if(winner==BOT){
        printf("\nYou lose!");
    }
    else printf("\nTie!");
}

void printWinnerHuman(char winner){
    if (winner==PLAYER){
        printf("\nPlayer 1 wins!");
    }
    else if(winner==PLAYER2){
        printf("\nPlayer 2 wins!");
    }
    else printf("\nTie!");
}

void playerMove(){
    int x,y;
    do{
        printf("\nYou are X!");
        printf("\nEnter move (Ex: 0 2): ");
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        if (board[x][y]!=' '){
            printf("Space already taken\n");
            printBoard();
        }
        else {
            board[x][y]=PLAYER;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(board[x][y]!=' ');

}

void player2Move(){
    int x,y;
    do{
        printf("You are O!");
        printf("Enter your move (Ex: 1 2): ");
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        if(board[x][y]!=' '){
            printf("\nSpace already taken!");
            printBoard();
        }
        else{
            board[x][y]=PLAYER2;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(board[x][y]!=' ');
}

void botMove(){
    //create random moves for bot
    srand(time(0));
    int x,y;
    if(checkFreeSpaces()>0){
        do{
            x=rand()%3;
            y=rand()%3;
        }
        while(board[x][y]!=' ');
        board[x][y]=BOT;
    }
    else printWinner(' ');
}

char checkWinner(){
    int i;
    //check rows winner
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (board[i][0]==board[i][1]&&board[i][0]==board[i][2]){
            return board[i][0];
        }
    }
    //check columns winner
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (board[0][i]==board[1][i]&&board[0][i]==board[2][i]){
            return board[0][i];
    }
    //check diagnols winner
        if(board[0][0]==board[1][1]&&board[0][i]==board[2][2]){
            return board[0][0];
    }
    //check second diagnols winner
        if(board[0][2]==board[1][1]&&board[0][2]==board[2][0]){
            return board[0][2];
    }
    return ' ';  //no winners
    }
}

//This is a test line to test github saving

int checkFreeSpaces(){
    int i,j;
    int freeSpaces=9;
    for(i=0;i<3;++i){
        for(j=0;j<3;++j){
            if (board[i][j]!=' '){
                freeSpaces--;
            }
        }
    }
    return freeSpaces;
}

void printBoard(){
    printf("   0   1   2");
    printf("\n |---|---|---|");
    printf("\n0| %c | %c | %c |",board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]);
    printf("\n |---|---|---|");
    printf("\n1| %c | %c | %c |",board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2]);
    printf("\n |---|---|---|");
    printf("\n2| %c | %c | %c |",board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]);
    printf("\n |---|---|---|");
}
    
void humanPlay(){
    resetBoard(); //reset default declaration of computer
        char winner =' ';
        while(winner == ' ' &&checkFreeSpaces()!=0){     //while there is no winner and there are still spaces
            printBoard();
            playerMove();
            winner=checkWinner();   //after every move of player, program checks if there is a winner and if there are spaces left.
            if(winner!=' ' || checkFreeSpaces()==0){
                break;
            }
            printBoard();
            player2Move();
            winner=checkWinner();
            if(winner!=' '||checkFreeSpaces()==0){          //if there is no spaces left and no winner, break loop.
                break;
            }
        }
        printBoard();
        printWinner(winner);
    }

    
void botPlay(){
    resetBoard(); //reset default declarartion of computer
        char winner =' ';
        while(winner == ' ' &&checkFreeSpaces()!=0){    //while there is no winner and there are still spaces
            printBoard();
            playerMove();
            winner=checkWinner();   //after every move of player, program checks if there is a winner and if there are spaces left.
            if(winner!=' ' || checkFreeSpaces()==0){
                break;
            }
            botMove();
            winner=checkWinner();
            if(winner!=' ' || checkFreeSpaces()==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        printBoard();
        printWinner(winner);
    }

void menuMain(){
    int choice;
    printf("*-------MAIN MENU-------*");
    printf("\n1. Play with other players");
    printf("\n2. Play with BOT");
    printf("\n3. Replay");
    printf("\n4. Player's information'");
    printf("\n5. Guide");
    printf("\n6. Exit");
    printf("\nPress number to choose: "); scanf("%d",&choice);

    
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            humanPlay();
            break;
        case 2:
            botPlay();
            break;
        case 3:
            
            break;
        case 4:
            
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("\n1.The game is played on a grid that's 3 squares by 3 squares");
            printf("\n2.You are X, your friend (or the computer in this case) is O. Players take turns putting their marks in empty squares.");
            printf("\n3.The first player to get 3 of her marks in a row (up, down, across, or diagonally) is the winner.");
            printf("\n3.The first player to get 3 of her marks in a row (up, down, across, or diagonally) is the winner.");
            printf("\n4.When all 9 squares are full, the game is over.");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Thank you for playing");
            break;
    }
}


int main(){
    
    menuMain();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!!

I tried changing from ++i to i++

Comment: dunno about the columns, but your first diagonal check is wrong,, it shouldn't use `i`. In fact it invokes UB because `i` is out of range (`==3`) when it gets there.

Comment: @yano I believe that I didn't use i in the diagonals winning conditions, I used all fixed numbers to decide the winner.

Comment: ... not according to the code you posted. Under `//check diagnols winner` you have `if(board[0][0]==board[1][1]&&board[0][i]==board[2][2])` .. see the `i` in there. It's supposed to be a `0`.

Comment: The second check for diagonals is also wrong. It compares the top left (0,0) to the middle (1,1) and then the top right (0,2) to the bottom left (2,0). It should probably be something like, `if(board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your checkWinners, function, you have a return statement within your for-loop:

```
char checkWinner(){
    int i;
    //check rows winner
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (board[i][0]==board[i][1]&&board[i][0]==board[i][2]){
            return board[i][0];
        }                // MISSING THIS CURLY BRACE FOR THE COLUMN WINNERS CHECK
    }
    //check columns winner
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (board[0][i]==board[1][i]&&board[0][i]==board[2][i]){
            return board[0][i];
    }               // OOPS
    //check diagnols winner
        if(board[0][0]==board[1][1]&&board[0][i]==board[2][2]){
            return board[0][0];
    }
    //check second diagnols winner
        if(board[0][2]==board[1][1]&&board[0][2]==board[2][0]){
            return board[0][2];
    }
    return ' ';  //no winners
    }               // SEE THIS, THIS IS A HINT SOMETHING IS WRONG
}
```

On first glance, you won't noticed that the `for` statement still continues after the `if` condition.

You probably meant this:

```
char checkWinner(){
    int i;
    //check rows winner
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (board[i][0]==board[i][1]&&board[i][0]==board[i][2]){
            return board[i][0];
        }
    }
    //check columns winner
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (board[0][i]==board[1][i]&&board[0][i]==board[2][i]){
            return board[0][i];
        } // ADD THIS
    }

    //check diagnols winner
    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1]&&board[0][i]==board[2][2]){
        return board[0][0];
    }

    //check second diagnols winner
    if(board[0][2]==board[1][1]&&board[0][2]==board[2][0]){
        return board[0][2];
    }
    return ' ';  //no winners
}
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: You had some misplaced curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of demonstration, assume the board is like this:

```
 XO
 XO
 X
```

Then `checkWinner` would see 3 of the same character (`' '`) in column 0 and return that character, which `humanPlay` and `botPlay` correctly ignore.